# Consolidation of data from different worksheets to master worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance for your help. I have written a code that would copy row 68 onwards till the last filled cell(in column A)from different worksheets and paste in a master worksheet called "Conso" from 3rd row. I wish to manually copy the header fields in the master sheet. But it gives run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error and not giving any result. Can you please help me as I am not an expert.

```
Sub MergeDataFromWorksheets()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim DestSh As Worksheet
  Dim erow As Long, lrowsh As Long, startrow As Long
  Dim CopyRng As Range
  startrow = 68
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
  End With
  Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Conso")
  If IsEmpty(Sheets("Conso").Range("A3:BT400")) = False Then
    Sheets("Conso").Range("A3:BT400").ClearContents
  End If
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> "Conso" And sh.Name <> "Data" And sh.Name <> "Template" Then
      erow = DestSh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
      lrowsh = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
      Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(startrow), sh.Rows(lrowsh))
      CopyRng.Copy
      Sheets("Conso").Range(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
  Next
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line raises the error? And why `xlPasteFormats`?

Comment: Also note that `If IsEmpty(Sheets("Conso").Range("A3:BT400")) = False` will always be correct. Try instead `If Application.CountA(Sheets("Conso").Range("A3:BT400")) > 0`